# Jasper report sum group totals in separate group and report summary

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report that is structured as follows:

Column header section
-all static text headers

Group A Header:
ID

Group B Header:
Date

Group C Header:
Currency Type

Detail Band:
Different Currency Values

Group C Footer:
Total Currency Value by Currency Type

Summary Band

---

What I now need is to add totals per currency type per ID as well as totals per currency type overall in the summary e.g.:

```
ID: 1234
Date:  01/01/2003
Currency: USD 
50 USD 
25 USD
10 USD
USD Total: 85

Currency: EUR
30 EUR
20 EUR
EUR Total: 50

Date: 01/05/2004
Currency: USD 
50 USD 
25 USD
10 USD
USD Total: 85

Currency: EUR
30 EUR
20 EUR
EUR Total: 50

1234 Totals: 
 USD 170
 EUR 100


Report Totals:
 USD 170
 EUR 100
```

I've tried a lot of different things. I've added variables with increment or reset group of ID to get those totals in the ID footer but they always just sum the complete values across currencies without taking currency type into consideration. I've tried to use subreports in those places that do the summation in their own reports in groups without success (always empty/null in main report regardless of data connection being passed). I'm using eclipse with the jaspersoft studio plugin, so the UI design is very limiting. Mainly trying to do it all through modification of the .jrxml directly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Write sub query. like select ...(all values from main query) from (main query) oder by Currency type

Comment: You mean add a subquery to the original query that supplies the data for the report? Not sure I can group the original query as it has tons of fields and it results in not a group by expression error. Or do you mean to create a second dataset with a separate query to use within the report? I tried that before too but again the connection never seems to work. Btw...the report doesn't run the query itself, that is run through Java which returns an object with all the data in it to the report. Thanks for your response btw.